# Edit the_content function

Tags: functions, content

I want to edit the default function `the_content()`. I know i can `add_filter('the_content', 'with_my_function')` but im having trouble outputting the old content with mine.

Heres an example of what im doing.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
function my_function()
{
    $write = 'hello world';
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
    echo $write.$content;
}
```

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like you are trying to prepend something to the beginning of the_content.

Try this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'se24265_my_function');
function se24265_my_function( $content )
{
    $write = 'hello world';
    $new_content = $write . $content;
    return $new_content;
}
```

Most filters will provide a parameter or two for your function to manipulate and then return.

Comment: Ahh thats right! Of course, i need to add the variable in the functions parameters. Thanks a lot, perfect. And im doing some `preg_replace()` throughout the content, i just needed help getting the content! ;)