# Wordpress add_action the_post hook

Tags: hooks

Now i face a problem, that i want to add a hook into the the_post. Then i use `print_r($post);` here display the my `print_r` content and again display the default content. because i am here in the_loop.so again the content was display.

```
add_action( 'the_content',  'custom_post' );

  function custom_post() {
    global $post, $wp_query;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    print_r($post);
  }
```

Here i need how to overwrite the default content of the the_post and display my own content.

This is possible  in a way, that i use the_title and the_content hook but here the function was call two times then its problem. so plz help me.

Comment: Not making much sense, what are you aiming to do? ie. What's the end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my answer here, if you are trying to replace the post content:

[Edit the_content function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24263/edit-the-content-function/24265#24265)